# If $|E| = 0$, then there exists $h \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $E+h$ does not contain a rational point.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Here we are trying to show that if a set $E$ has zero (Lebesgue) measure, then there is a point $h \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $E+h$ does not contain a rational point.

I tried to solve this using contradiction. The argument goes as follows: Suppose that for every $h \in \mathbb{R}$ we can find a rational point in $E+h$. From here I am trying to show that if this is the case, then the measure of $E$ would not be zero, thus proving our claim. However, I am not sure how to formulate the argument to get to the end.

I already looked at the previous questions posted on here for this type of problem, but it did not make much sense to me.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $r \in E + h$ iff $-h \in E +(- r)$.  The set of rationals is countable. What do you know about the measure of a countable union?

Comment: Well, I know that the measure of a countable union is equal to the sum of the measures.

Comment: And the sum of $0$'s is ...

Comment: Is $0$ of course. I am very sorry, but I still do not see how that leads to a contradiction.

Comment: But the measure of $\mathbb R$ is not zero.  So if you remove a set of measure $0$, there are points left over.